# Service Worker throwing errors when fetching MP3 audio

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, service-worker

I would like my web app to be promoted for **Add to Home Screen** for users on Android+Chrome. (inspired by : [Chromium Blog entry](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/04/reaching-and-re-engaging-users-on.html))

To do this I need a **Service Worker** running, even a dummy one. (Chrome needs the Service Worker as proof that I'm serious about web apps)

So I've created a dummy Service Worker with no content. It gets served with the correct no-cache headers, served over HTTPS, and is scoped to the whole domain.

Thing work generally, however every time I try to create an audio element on the fly :

```
jQuery( '<audio><source src="/beep.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source></audio>' );
```

...my console shows some unhappiness (taken from Chrome Canary for better messaging from the service worker thread, but basically the same output is in Chrome current) :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my.domain.com/some/page' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video ''. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

GET https://my.domain.com/beep.mp3 400 (Service Worker Fallback Required)
```

I suppose it's important to note that, obviously, I'm not retrieving the resource directly, just creating the element and letting the browser retrieve the MP3.

The MP3 does actually get fetched (I am able to run the .play() method on the audio element). It's just the errors in my console log are piling up and makes me suspicious of how reliable this approach is. Also, incidentally, in Canary (but not current) the failure will change my "HTTPS lock" indicator from green to "warning" (so, future problem).

The audio source is from the same domain as the page, and both are HTTPS. So the "Mixed Content" message from the service worker thread is strange; it references a video with '' as the url.

**Question** : Am I doing something wrong or is this a Chrome bug? Do I need more than a dummy (empty) service worker? If I'm doing something wrong, I would like to find a best-practice/long-term type solution rather than hack something together, but I'll take what I can get. ;)

Comment: try using the entire url in the src attribute: https://my.domain.com/beep.mp3

Comment: Where's your service worker code?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a bug. This is the issue on Google code:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477685

Comment: Not sure if that's the same bug. That bug sounds related to CORS, but everything I'm doing is same-domain, same-protocol (I tried with and without the scheme+host; no difference). The proposed work-around/solution over there also involved a Service Worker that was specifically re-writing the request, whereas my Service Worker should be doing nothing but passing the request/response directly through.